# Linear differential equation of 2nd order with variable coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(1-x^2)y''+xy'-y=x(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

I found $u=x$ (because here $P + xQ = 0$)
but I have issues in finding $'v' (v''+(P+(2/u)*u')v'=R/u$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let me skecth the solution of the ODE:

1. As is usual for a linear inhomogeneous ODE, we first try to solve the homogeneous equation,
   $$
   (1-x^2)y''+xy'-y=0. \tag{1}
   $$
2. Since one of the two linearly independent solutions to $(1)$ has already been found, namely $y_1(x)=x$, we can find the other, $y_2$, with the help of the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)
   $$
   W=y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2. \tag{2}
   $$
   Indeed, dividing both sides of $(2)$ by $y_1^2$, we obtain
   $$
   \frac{W}{y_1^2}=\frac{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}{y_1^2}=\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'
   \implies y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int\frac{W(x)}{y_1^2(x)}\,dx. \tag{3}
   $$
3. In the case of Eq. $(1)$, the Wronskian satisfies the first order ODE
   $$
   (1-x^2)W'(x)+xW(x)=0, \tag{4}
   $$
   which has as solution
   $$
   W(x)=A(1-x^2)^{1/2}. \tag{5}
   $$
4. Replacing $y_1(x)$ and $W(x)$ in $(3)$ with their explicit expressions and performing the integral, we obtain
   $$
   y_2(x)=-A\left(x\arcsin x+(1-x^2)^{1/2}\right)+Bx. \tag{6}
   $$
   Without loss of generality, in what follows we shall set $A=1$ and $B=0$ in the expressions for $W$ and $y_2$.
5. Having found $y_1$ and $y_2$, we may now use the method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to determine a particular solution to the original ODE. The result is
   $$
   y_p(x)=-y_1(x)\int\frac{y_2(x)}{W(x)}f(x)\,dx + y_2(x)\int\frac{y_1(x)}{W(x)}f(x)\,dx,
   \tag{7}
   $$
   where
   $$
   f(x)=\frac{x(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{1-x^2}=x(1-x^2)^{1/2} \tag{8}
   $$
   is the RHS of the inhomogeneous ODE divided by the coefficient of $y''$. (The derivation of Eq. $(7)$ can be found in the highlighted reference.)
6. Plugging into $(7)$ the explicit expressions of $y_1$, $y_2$, $W$ and $f$, and performing the integrals, we obtain
   $$
   y_p(x)=-\frac{1}{9}x(1-x^2)^{3/2}. \tag{9}
   $$
7. The final solution is $y(x)=C_1y_1(x)+C_2y_2(x)+y_p(x)$,
   where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.